# DataGridView: Time sheet similar to Outlook Calendar

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to create a time sheet for employee in datagrid view, where employee can select working hours of each day.
I want to display DataGrid in such a way that hours of day appear as columns (24 columns) and rows appear as days (30-31 depending upon month), similar to Outlook Calendar thing where we select number of hours for some event on a particular day.
So that when employee selects cells I can get work time from corresponding selected columns.
Can some one point me to direction how I can label my rows and columns with dates and time.

Answer (score 0):

Use first column of DGV for the dates and another 24 columns for the 24 hours range (total 25 columns). Go to `ColumnCollection` to set Column `HeaderText` property. Have a database of 3-4 columns storing datetime, user, events, etc. When you load the database, fill DGV according to datetime column.

Use the `CellClick` or `CellDoubleClick` Event for the employees to select the cell.

Do comment if I miss something.